# Not sure how to create an if statement saying if <iframe> else something else

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, iframe

I am in Magento, but I figure this can be done with normal PHP. Maybe I am wrong. I am inexperienced when it comes to PHP.

I have an issue where I need to kill an iframe from trying to display in a dropdown. But it still needs to display when you get to that specific landing page. So I can't kill it everywhere, just on the dropdown. So what I need to write is when that iframe does try to show up in the dropdown, it gets replaced with normal text.

I tried finding an answer to this but no luck.

Thank you for your time in advance.

This is the code being used for that specific dropdown. There is no if statement running right now to kill it. I tried a couple of things that didn't come close to working.

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(54);
$categories = $category->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'description'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter( $category->getChildren() );
$categories->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$categories->getSelect()->limit(1);
?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<div>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>">
        <img alt="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" style="width: 100%; max-height: 240px; box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #aaa;-ms-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #aaa;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #aaa;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #aaa;border: 1px solid #F7EBD2;" />
    </a>
    <br />    
    <h3>Spotlight Watch</h3>
    <p>
    <?php
        $sdesc = $category->getDescription();
        $sdesc = trim($sdesc);
        $limit = 300;
        if (strlen($sdesc) > $limit) {
            $sdesc = substr($sdesc, 0, strrpos(substr($sdesc, 0, $limit), ' '));
        }
    ?>
    <?php echo $sdesc."..."; ?>
    </p>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>" class="go">View <?php echo $category->getName(); ?> Watches...</a>      
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Iframe in drop-down, huh... Please show how this drop-down has been coded, and what have you tried so far.

Comment: http://www.mccaskill.fmwebd.com/watches/watches-watch-brands/watches-rolex.html

This is the page that will display the iframe. And up above, you will see the "Watches" dropdown. Right now I have the dropdown randomizing the 4 Watch Brands. So Rolex's will show up on occasion.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about that. Let me take it off.

EDIT: Now taken off.